# clock control in cocoa/objective-c

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, controls

The Cocoa programming for Mac OS X 3rd edition book has the following screen capture at page 85.

How can I get the clock control, and how to use it? I can't seem to find it with Interface Builder.

[image]

#### ADDED

I got some good examples [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DatePicker/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004134).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats `NSDatePicker` control and you can change it from calendar to clock face in its options.